# Website Beta Signup - Track source and what page they signed up on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I just added a Beta Tester model to my app, and would like to track the following:

1. Page they signed up on, as the beta signup form will be on multiple pages on my site
2. What drove them to my site (ex: direct url, Facebook, email invite, Google Adwords, etc)

Any recommendations on how to achieve the goals above would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add_signupsource_to_beta_tester (or something like that) model and send in a parameter via a hidden field in the sign-up form via the URL (/signup?source=signup). Or you could assign a variable for the sign-up form inside your controller.

Code in this situation could look like:

Your controller action

```
...

def index
  @signup_source = "index"
end

def beta_user
  @signup_source = "beta"
end
...
```

Your signup form's invisible field

```
<%= f.hidden_field :signup_source, value: @signup_source, readonly: true %>
```

I would also recommend you to try yandex.metrika - it's a Russian analog of Google analitycs, but with some additional cool features - specifically it can record user actions and you can see your site with his eyes. Very cool. It also creates heat-maps for clicks. And it is free. Here's the [link](https://metrika.yandex.ru/?&ncrnd=5475). It does not conflict with Analytics, so you can use both.

Comment: Thanks Denis!  The hidden field makes perfect sense for #1, but any chance you could provide a quick code sample for that?

Comment: can yandex be implemented with G Tag Manager?

Comment: Updated answer with an example

Comment: @PetrHavlík yandex is a stand-alone analytics system, it works separately, but has no conflicts with other trackers